# little endian in python

Tags: python

Mysystem endian is little,

```
>>> struct.pack('i',70691357)
'\x1d\xaa6\x04'
>>> int("0x436aa1d",16)
70691357
```

to overturn 0x436aa1d  is `1d a a6  43` is not    `1d  a a6 04` ,what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a pretty print output you can use `binascii.hexlify()`

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('i',70691357))
'1daa3604'
```

Answer (score 2):

The string that was printed out should be interpreted as `0x1d` `0xaa` `ord('6')` `0x04`, where `ord('6') = 0x36`. Reversing the bytes and putting it together makes 0x0436aa1d.

Comment: can i make it displayed as `\x1d\xaa\x36\x04` in python terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a one-liner like this to display the bytes of a string in hexadecimal regardless of their value:

```
def hexify(s):
    return ''.join(map(lambda c: '\\x{:02x}'.format(ord(c)), s))

print hexify(struct.pack('i', 70691357))  # \x1d\xaa\x36\x04
```